# syscall assembly in ser/usys.S for the xv6 os

Tags: c, assembly, riscv, xv6

In the `user/usys.S` here a fragment which is generate by the [usys.pl script](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/a1da53a5a12e21b44a2c79d962a437fa2107627c/user/usys.pl)

```
.global sbrk
sbrk:
 li a7, SYS_sbrk
 ecall
 ret
.global sleep
sleep:
 li a7, SYS_sleep
 ecall
 ret
.global uptime
uptime:
 li a7, SYS_uptime
 ecall
 ret
```

The user functions will need to call the kernel syscalls, since just the kernel have the privilege to execute the instruction needed.
So the user functions need to be write in assembly so that can use the riscv `ecall` instruction that will trigger the kernel function.
How the arguments are passed to this kernel syscalls functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's just talk about `sleep`.  In one of your earlier questions, you posted a link to the [user.h header file](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/a1da53a5a12e21b44a2c79d962a437fa2107627c/user/user.h#L6).
That header file tells your C compiler what arguments the function takes and what the function returns, on this line:

```
int sleep(int);
```

After processing that line, the C compiler knows that `sleep` expects a single `int` argument.  Therefore, when you try to call that function in a C program, the compiler will ensure that an argument is passed to the function using the standard way of passing `int` arguments to functions on your platform.  This is called the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).  For example, the calling convention might say to put the argument on the stack or to put it in a specific register.  You can view the assembly generated by your C compiler to see what it does when it calls `sleep`.

I don't really know the details of what `ecall` does, but at some point it should trigger some code in your kernel, and that code would also know about your platform's calling convention, so it can retrieve the argument that your C compiler passed to `sleep`.

For more details about the kernel side, look at the [the source code of sys_sleep](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/077323a8f0b3440fcc3d082096a2d83fe5461d70/kernel/sysproc.c#L56) and see how it calls `argint` to get its argument.

Comment: Thanks you very much for answer, I was expecting there was some code in the user side which as you suggest put the argument in some register and then call the ecall instruction .. that is what have confused me ... I did not see that code yet, but I will give a close look at the code you suggest me to see

Comment: If the calling convention for system calls was different than the normal calling convention for C functions, you would see some code in the `sleep` assembly routine (which you quoted above) to copy arguments to the right place.  But it looks like this OS was designed nicely, so that is not needed.

Comment: since arguments are set by the user .. I'm expecting to see this passage on the user code .since is the user code that call the kernel code so it up to him setup the argumetns right?.. maybe I'm missed something I need to better look at calling convention

Comment: Yes, the argument is set by the user.  The C compiler is a tool the user uses to help set the argument.  Again, you can look at the assembly code your C compiler generates for `sleep(100)`.

Comment: For example, you can use the Compiler Explorer to compile that code and see that the C compiler sets register a0 to 100:  https://godbolt.org/z/oavWbb75h

Comment: @pav: If the user-space function-calling convention matches the kernel's system-call calling convention, then wrapper functions that just pass along their args to the system call don't need to touch the arg registers.  (An interesting example of this is x86-64 System V, where the convention *almost* matches, except the kernel uses R10 instead of RCX as the 4th arg, for reasons, so wrapper functions need to mov RCX to R10 as well as putting the call number in a register.  Actual libc functions will also check the return value and set errno on error, and maybe even restart the call on EINTR)

Comment: @DavidGrayson thanks! I see that the compiler could handle when the argument are provided in the source code but in case is provided dynamically for example as command line input .. I do not still see but probably I should take a little time to look at it.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for your note, do you have some reading to suggest to better undestand the different kind of convention kernel and user spaces can have.

Comment: You seem to have some general fear about C compilers being unable to do their job.  There is nothing magical about what a C compiler does, and if a compiler were not able to produce code that reads inputs, does computations, and calls an externally-defined function then it would be pretty broken.  I suggest playing around with https://godbolt.org (or your xv6 toolchain) some more to look at the code generated for the cases you care about.  I don't know what else I can say about this.  Please accept my answer for this question.